# Excel.run with delayForCellEdit does not work nested

Tags: office-js

The `Excel.run({ delayForCellEdit: true }, async (context) => {})` only work with the context in the function passing into it.

In the nested case `Excel.run({ delayForCellEdit: true }, async (context) => Excel.run(async (context2) => { })})`,
the operations related to `context2` won't be delayed if user is in cell edit mode.

The following script will throw cell edit mode error if user is editing during the script running.

```
    async function run() {
      console.log("Now, double click a cell to enter edit mode!");
      await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
      });
      console.log("Start execute! please ensure the you are in cell edit mode!");
      await Excel.run({ delayForCellEdit: true }, async (context) => {
        return Excel.run(async (context2) => {
          context2.workbook.getActiveCell().values = [[0]];
        });
      });
    }
    /** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
    async function tryCatch(callback) {
      try {
        await callback();
      } catch (error) {
        // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is by-design. Either just un-nested your call, or mark your nested `Excel.run` with the `delayForCellEdit` flag.